# Java / JVMTI: Usage of JavaVM-parameter in Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM, char*, void)

Tags: java, oracle, jvm, java-native-interface, jvmti

I am currently working with JVMTI very the first time .

I mostly use the [JVM(TM) Tool Interface Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#onload) if any questions come up.

But what I could not find out is: What can the JavaVM-parameter be used to *except getting the environment* by calling GetEnv(...) on it? Is this the only purpose?

I was not able to find any further documentation neither on the JavaVM class itself nor on this parameter in particular. Probably I was just blind and someone can point me in the right direction (Explainations, Documentation, Tutorials, etc.).

Here some typical example code on the parameter useage I've seen so far:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, char *options, void *reserved) {
  jvmtiEnv              *jvmti;
  jvmtiError             error;
  jint                   res;
  jvmtiCapabilities      capabilities;
  jvmtiEventCallbacks    callbacks;

  res = (*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1);
  // Here the code goes on
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaVM` structure is a part of [Java Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).

It contains the following functions:

- GetEnv
- DestroyJavaVM
- AttachCurrentThread
- AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon
- DetachCurrentThread